# I have a list of strings, and I'd like to call INSERTDATA with multiple rows for each item in my list. How can I do this?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of names.

```
| aaa | =insertdata("http://url/api/" & A1) |
| bbb | =insertdata("http://url/api/" & A2) |
| ccc | =insertdata("http://url/api/" & A3) |
```

The problem is insert data is going to insert more than one row, and I need to offset each `insertdata()` by the number of rows it returns. I also have thousands of names in my list, so I would like some way to do this automated.

I could always write a script, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in function or other feature that does this.

Comment: There is a good way to do this depending *not* on the number of names you have, but he size of the returns.  about how many rows does each api call?

Comment: The one that I tested returned about 5k rows and 2 columns. There are about 7000 names, if that matters.

Comment: I don't know what "Transpose each one so that it fits, then Flatten" means in the context of a spreadsheet.
--
No, the data has two columns, a date and then a number. It's two dimensional. I also need to add a column with the name that is being looked up for each row returned.
--
EDIT: Oh, you mean this: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262 Let me look at that.

Comment: You know, I think I'm just going to do this in Rails and use a more featureful programming language. MattKing and Calculuswhiz, Thanks for the help